# G*power -> MANOVA (global effects) confusion with given effect size

Tags: effect-size, manova, gpower

I'm working with G*power to calculate the sample size for my experiment.
At the moment I'm a little bit confused handling the **effect size values**.
I have 3 IV (3 groups) and 2 DV => so i will use the MANOVA.

**SETTINGS:**
I start G*power and select:
Test Family: F-Test
Statistical Test: MANOVA (global effects)
Type of analysis: A priori
alpha: 0.05
power: 0.95

**PROBLEM:**
G*power proposes Pillai's V **Effect size f²(V) = 0.0625**
What's confusing me is the suggested value of 0.0625!

The variables I found in the literatur for estimating the effect size are f² or eta² resp. eta²(part) for ANOVA/MANOVA etc. I know f, f² and eta² can be converted in each other.
But the suggested value in G*power (0.0625) is the well known value for eta² (medium effect).
Though the usual value for Cohen's f² = 0.15 (medium effect).
*see table below*

This really confuses me. Is it a mistyping in G*power (I do not think so) but what is my fallacy?
If Gpower names it f²(V) I ought to input 0.15 for a medium effect. But then i'll get completely different suggestions for the sample size.
**Why uses Gpower the values of eta² for f²?**

I know the following values for the effect size from literature:

| Effect size | small | medium | big |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| f | .10 | .25 | .40 |
| eta² / eta²(part) | .01 | **.06** | .14 |
| Cohen's f² | .02 | **.15** | .35 |

Many Thanks for any help

Tom

Comment: I found this link that might be helpful? http://core.ecu.edu/psyc/wuenschk/StatHelp/PowerAnalysis_Overview.pdf It appears f2 is literally .25 x .25 = .0625.

Comment: The values cited above for f-squared are those Cohen recommended for multiple regression, not for ANOVA/MANOVA. For ANOVA/MANOVA just square the benchmarks for f.